# How to pass v-for data into modal in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

After listing my posts, I want to make a modal that when open will get the youtube id from that exact post and paste it into the b-embed src link to show the youtube video corresponding to the post

```js
<template>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li id="posts" v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.name">
            <b-card no-body style="max-width: 20rem;" class="md-elevation-12" v-if="post.tag === 'game'">
                <b-card-body>
                    <md-card-media>
                        <img :src="
                'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + post.yturl + '/hqdefault.jpg'
              " />
                    </md-card-media>
                    <b-card-title>{{ post.name }}</b-card-title>
                    <b-card-text></b-card-text>
                </b-card-body>
                <b-card-body>
                    <b-button v-b-modal.modal-xl="'game'" @click="sendInfo(post)" variant="outline-secondary">Xem</b-button>
                </b-card-body>
            </b-card>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <b-modal size="xl" id="game" :title="selectedPost.name">
        <b-embed type="iframe" aspect="16by9" :src="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + selectedPost.yturl" allowfullscreen></b-embed>
    </b-modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import db from "@/db";

export default {
    name: "GameView",
    name: "MediaCover",
    data() {
        return {
            showDialog: false,
            posts: [],
            selectedPost: '',
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 0,
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        playing() {},
        modalId(i) {
            return "game";
        },
        sendInfo(post) {
            this.selectedPost = post;
        },
    },
    props: {
        msg: String,
    },
    created() {
        db.collection("holoposts")
            .orderBy("date")
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    this.posts.push(doc.data());
                });
            });
    },
};
</script>
```

But as you can see, it is encountering a problem of cannot specifying the yturl since the modal is outside of the v-for. And if I put it inside, the modal will loop open all the posts.

---

EDIT
Since this is solved, I will edit the above code into the right one so anyone can see

Comment: `post` is only defined inside your `v-for`. So you need to place it in the view model, as `selectedPostId` and populate it when clicking the open modal button. If you need more help, please provide either a [mcve] or at least a sample of what your db is returning. There also a few more problems: you're duplicating `name` and `item` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single modal is needed, just the content changes when the selected post changes.
You can try something like this:

```
<b-button v-b-modal.modal-xl="'game'" click="sendInfo(post)"
<!-- -->
<b-modal size="xl" id="game">
  <b-embed v-if="selectedPost" type="iframe" aspect="16by9" :src="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + selectedPost.yturl" allowfullscreen></b-embed>
</b-modal>
```

And make sure selectedPost is returned from data(), not sure why it's outside.

Comment: So I add it in like this?

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedPost: ' ',
            },
        };
    },
};

Comment: Yea like other variables you have in data(). A default value of null would be more appropriate than '' but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I got it working just as I want, but I wanna add a little something.
It's @click, only click doesn't seem to pass the data.

Comment: Yea I wrote this a bit too fast ;) It's indeed an event, good job.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can allow you code as it but in the modal change `post.yturl` to `chosenPost.yturl`, add it to `data` and add an event(for example click event) to the post card and when it update it to be the `chosenPost` like so `@click.prevent = choosePost(post)` and then in your data methods add this method

```js
choosePost(post) {
  this.chosenPost = post;
}
```

That should do